# Certain websites won't load with DHCP server

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp

I recently configured a server using Windows Server 2008 to take over from my router using DHCP Server.

I disabled my router from assigning IPs too.

All works well, except for certain sites that refuse to load e.g. "Firefox could not find www.amazon.co.uk"

http://www.google.co.uk/

http://www.amazon.co.uk/

http://www.jobsite.co.uk/

I think it may have something to do with co.uk domain.

If I reboot the server everything goes back to normal but of course thats not a good solution to do that every other day.
Does anyone know of this problem or what it might be - I am very new to server technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Windows server is acting as DNS server possibly the problem is on  dns root servers queries as per this microsoft support kb [Article ID: 968372](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968372).
The solution is the following:
o resolve the issue and continue using root hints, change the MaxCacheTTL registry value to 2 days or greater.

Warning: Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly by using Registry Editor or another method. These problems might require you to reinstall the operating system. Microsoft cannot guarantee that these problems can be solved. Modify the registry at your own risk.

1. Start Registry Editor (regedit.exe).
2. Locate the following registry key:
3. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters
4. On the Edit menu, click New, click DWORD (32-bit) Value, and then add the following value:
   Value: MaxCacheTTL
   Data Type: DWORD
   Data value: 0x2A300 (172800 seconds in decimal, or 2 days)
5. Click OK.
6. Quit Registry Editor.
7. Restart the DNS Server service.

Comment: Looking at the Microsoft link you gave there - looks exactly what I have been experiencing, hope that fix works. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

perhaps your windows DHCP server is not serving the nameserver data to clients requesting DHCP leases. or perhaps the DNS server IPs it is sharing are invalid, pointing to your router, which no longer runs a caching nameserver, etc.